# How to pass value Recycler onClicklistener in an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have this onClickListener, I want pass the value total outside of its Listener

```
serviceOrderAdapter = new ServiceOrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(), orderCategoryModels, new ServiceOrderAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClickListener(OrderCategoryModel orderCategoryModel, int position) {

        total = orderCategoryModel.getOrderPrice();
        changeSelectedService(position);
    }
});
```

How do I do that?

and i want to know how to get total value from two onClicklistener and sum them in the activity.

UPDATE 1:

Here is my code of the project

I already have a have listener for get the position of the item in
recycler view but how to implement pass value to it?

**OrderActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Order");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        initDatePicker();

        dateButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
        timeButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_time);

        fData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mOrderDatabase = fData.getReference("order");
        mExtraDatabase = fData.getReference("extraService");

        orderCategoryModels = new ArrayList<>();
        extraServiceModels = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerViewOrder = findViewById(R.id.recycles_order);
        recyclerViewExtraService = findViewById(R.id.recycles_extra);

        txt_uang_service = findViewById(R.id.txt_uang_service);
        txt_uang_extra = findViewById(R.id.txt_uang_extra);
        txt_total_uang = findViewById(R.id.txt_total_uang);
        arrow_icon = findViewById(R.id.img_btn_next);

        recyclerViewOrder.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3));
        recyclerViewExtraService.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
//        recyclerViewOrder.setAdapter(serviceOrderAdapter);


        serviceOrderAdapter = new ServiceOrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(), orderCategoryModels, new ServiceOrderAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClickListener(OrderCategoryModel orderCategoryModel, int position) {

                total = orderCategoryModel.getOrderPrice();

                changeSelectedService(position);

            }

        });


        extraServiceAdapter = new ExtraServiceAdapter(getApplicationContext(), extraServiceModels, new ExtraServiceAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickListener(ExtraServiceModel extraServiceModel, int position) {


                changeSelectedExtra(position);
            }
        });

        valueEventListener = mOrderDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                orderCategoryModels.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    OrderCategoryModel orderCategoryModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(OrderCategoryModel.class);
                    orderCategoryModel.setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    currentIndex = 0;

                    final String s = getIntent().getExtras().getString("catName");
                    if (s.equals(orderCategoryModel.getCatName())) {

                        orderCategoryModels.add(orderCategoryModel);

                    }
                }

//                serviceOrderAdapter = new ServiceOrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(),orderCategoryModels);
                serviceOrderAdapter.setSelectedPosition(-1);
                recyclerViewOrder.setAdapter(serviceOrderAdapter);
                serviceOrderAdapter.setCatModels(ServiceOrderAdapter.getInstance().getAllOrder());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.w(TAG, "helooooooooooooo" + error.getMessage());
            }
        });


        valueEventListener = mExtraDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                extraServiceModels.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ExtraServiceModel extraServiceModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(ExtraServiceModel.class);
                    extraServiceModel.setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    currentIndex = 0;

                    final String a = getIntent().getExtras().getString("catName");
                    if (a.equals(extraServiceModel.getCatName())) {

                        extraServiceModels.add(extraServiceModel);
                    }
                }

                extraServiceAdapter.setSelectedPosition(-1);
                recyclerViewExtraService.setAdapter(extraServiceAdapter);
                extraServiceAdapter.setExtraModels(ExtraServiceAdapter.getInstance().getAllExtra());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.w(TAG, "helooooooooooooo" + error.getMessage());
            }
        });


        arrow_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//                bundle.putString("extraCash" , extraServiceModels.get(position).getExtraPrice());
//                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactDetailActivity.class);
//                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }



    private void initDatePicker() {
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                month = month + 1;
                String date = makeDateString(dayOfMonth, month, year);
                dateButton.setText(date);
//                dateButton.setText(getTodaysDate());
            }
        };

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        int style = AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT;

        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, style, dateSetListener, year, month, day);
//        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
    }

    private String getTodaysDate() {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        month = month + 1;
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return makeDateString(day, month, year);
    }

    private String makeDateString(int dayOfMonth, int month, int year) {
        return getMonthFormat(month) + " " + dayOfMonth + " " + year;
    }

    private String getMonthFormat(int month) {
        if (month == 1) {
            return "JAN";
        }
        else if (month == 2) {
            return "FEB";
        }
        else if (month == 3) {
            return "MAR";
        }
        else if (month == 4) {
            return "APR";
        }
        else if (month == 5) {
            return "MAY";
        }
        else if (month == 6) {
            return "JUN";
        }
        else if (month == 7) {
            return "JUL";
        }
        else if (month == 8) {
            return "AUG";
        }
        else if (month == 9) {
            return "SEP";
        }
        else if (month == 10) {
            return "OCT";
        }
        else if (month == 11) {
            return "NOV";
        }
        else if (month == 12) {
            return "DEX";
        }
        return "Jan";
    }

    public void changePrice(int total){
        serviceOrderAdapter.notifyItemChanged(serviceOrderAdapter.getSelectedPosition());
        total = new OrderCategoryModel().getOrderPrice();
    }

    public void changeSelectedService(int index) {
        serviceOrderAdapter.notifyItemChanged(serviceOrderAdapter.getSelectedPosition());
        currentIndex = index;
        serviceOrderAdapter.setSelectedPosition(currentIndex);
        serviceOrderAdapter.notifyItemChanged(currentIndex);
    }

    public void changeSelectedExtra(int index) {
        extraServiceAdapter.notifyItemChanged(extraServiceAdapter.getSelectedPosition());
        currentIndex = index;
        extraServiceAdapter.setSelectedPosition(currentIndex);
        extraServiceAdapter.notifyItemChanged(currentIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void openDatePicker(View view) {
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }

    public void openTimerPicker(View view) {
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                hour = hourOfDay;
                minute = minute;
                timeButton.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute));
            }
        };

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, onTimeSetListener, hour, minute, true);

        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }

}
```

**ServitOrderAdapter.java**

```
public class ServiceOrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServiceOrderAdapter.ServiceOrderViewHolder> {


    public ServiceOrderAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<OrderCategoryModel> orderCategoryModels, RecyclerItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.orderCategoryModels = orderCategoryModels;
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    private ServiceOrderAdapter(){
        if (null == orderCategoryModels){
            orderCategoryModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ServiceOrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.service_card, parent, false);
            return new ServiceOrderAdapter.ServiceOrderViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ServiceOrderViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {

        final OrderCategoryModel orderCategoryModel = orderCategoryModels.get(position);
        holder.txt_service_name.setText(orderCategoryModel.getServiceName());



        if (orderCategoryModel != null){
            if (selectedPosition == position){
                holder.parent.setCardBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            }else {
                holder.parent.setCardBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        }

        holder.bind(orderCategoryModel, listener);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderCategoryModels.size();
    }

    public void setCatModels(ArrayList<OrderCategoryModel> orderCategoryModels){
        this.orderCategoryModels = orderCategoryModels;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static ServiceOrderAdapter getInstance(){
        if (null == instance){
            instance = new ServiceOrderAdapter();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static ArrayList<OrderCategoryModel> getAllOrder(){
        return orderCategoryModels;
    }

    public class ServiceOrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private CardView parent;
        private TextView txt_service_name, txt_price_service;

        public ServiceOrderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
            txt_service_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_service_name);
            txt_price_service = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_service);
        }

        public void bind(final OrderCategoryModel orderCategoryModel, final RecyclerItemClickListener listener) {


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.onClickListener(orderCategoryModel, getAdapterPosition());

                }
            });

        }
    }

    public interface RecyclerItemClickListener {

        void onClickListener(OrderCategoryModel orderCategoryModel, int position);

    }



    public int getSelectedPosition() {
        return selectedPosition;
    }

    public void setSelectedPosition(int selectedPosition) {
        this.selectedPosition = selectedPosition;
    }


}
```

Im sorry for the long reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just small changes, my code is working to my desire.

```
extraServiceAdapter = new ExtraServiceAdapter(getApplicationContext(), extraServiceModels, new ExtraServiceAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickListener(ExtraServiceModel extraServiceModel, int position) {


            currentExtraPrice = extraServiceModel.getExtraPrice();
            changeSelectedExtra(position);

            onPriceChanged(currentExtraPrice + currentServicePrice);
        }
    });
```

---

```
serviceOrderAdapter = new ServiceOrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(), orderCategoryModels, new ServiceOrderAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickListener(OrderCategoryModel orderCategoryModel, int position) {

            currentServicePrice = orderCategoryModel.getOrderPrice();


            changeSelectedService(position);

            onPriceChanged(currentExtraPrice + currentServicePrice);

        }

    });
```

---

```
   public void onPriceChanged(int total) {

    txt_total_uang.setText(String.valueOf(total));



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Interfaces` for that.

Create an `interface` with a method `onPriceChanged(price: Int)`

```
interface PriceChangeListener {
    void onPriceChanged(int total);
}
```

In `activity` or `fragment`, containing `recyclerView`, implement `PriceChangeListener` interface, and `override` `onPriceChanged` method and use `total` value there.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements PriceChangedListener {
    
    @Override
    public void onPriceChanged(int total) {
    
    }
}
```

Inside `recyclerView's` adapter, change its constructor to accept `PriceChangedListener`

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    
    private PriceChangeListener priceChangedListener;

    public MyAdapter(PriceChangeListener priceChangedListener) {
        this.priceChangeListener = priceChangeListener;
    }
}
```

Call `onPriceChanged()` inside `onClickListener()`

```
serviceOrderAdapter = new ServiceOrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(), orderCategoryModels, new ServiceOrderAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClickListener(OrderCategoryModel orderCategoryModel, int position) {

        total = orderCategoryModel.getOrderPrice();
        changeSelectedService(position);
        
        priceChangeListener.onPriceChanged(total); // send price to the activity
    }
});
```

Comment: can constructor contain 2 listener?

Comment: and what is the difference between onClick in the main activity with onClick in the adapter viewholder?

Comment: You can add as many `listeners` as you want in the `constructor`. Instead of adding multiple `constructors`, add multiple `methods` in your interface and override them.

Comment: If you are adding a `clickListener` to `recyclerView` in `mainActivity`, that would be on the whole `recyclerView` not on each single `viewHolder`. But, we need to listen to each different `viewHolder's` click of the `recyclerView`, that's why we are setting `clickListener` inside the adapter not in the main activity.

Comment: `public ServiceOrderAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<OrderCategoryModel> orderCategoryModels, RecyclerItemClickListener listener, PriceChangedListener priceChangedListener) {
        
this.mContext = mContext;
        this.orderCategoryModels = orderCategoryModels;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.priceChangedListener = priceChangedListener;
    }`

is this the correct implement when using 2 listener in 1 constructor ?

Comment: and because i added new listener to the constructor, i need to add the new listener to onclicklistener parameter but i dont know how @Praveen

Comment: should i change the bind method in the viewholder too?

Comment: after add this `priceChangeListener.onPriceChanged(total);`

i can use total globally in the activity?

Comment: call `priceChangeListener.onPriceChanged(total);` inside of `clickListener` of view inside of `bind` method.

Comment: You don't need multiple `listeners`, you can add multiple `methods` inside a single `interface`